# Multiple OR comparison

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I have a group of variables , say b1-b30 and i need to test same condition on same variables among themselves like, if b1='a' or b2='a' or b3='a'.. and so on. is there any solution in SAS macros or using of sas arrays to do this task to avoid writing this explicitly.
sample code is like this:

```
data test;
    input d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 ;
cards;
1 2 1 1 0
2 3 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
0 2 1 0 2
0 4 0 2 2
0 0 0 0 3
;
run;

data want;
    set test;
    if d1=1 or d2=1 or d3=1 or d4=1 then flag=1;
    else flag=0;
run;
```

so i have around 50 variable , to test same condition and flag it .

Answer (score 2):

You could use `WHICHN()` or `WHICHC()` functions.

```
flag1 = not 0=whichn(1,of d1-d4);
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN operator with array-name will work but you would need to make an array for each variable group.  Using WHICHN would be easier.

```
array d[5];
if 1 in d then flag2=1; else flag2=0;
```